cmake not found during dlib installation using pip (even though cmake installed correctly)
i want to install dlib in a virtual environment using pip. pip told me that it requires cmake to install dlib. cool, i installed cmake. tried to install dlib again, it still tells me to install cmake. i also don't understand why does the code try to access __main__.py on the cmake executable (see below)
here are the errors that pip gave
 Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      <string>:210: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
      <string>:211: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
      <string>:212: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
        File "C:\myFiles\dev\Hair_Style_Recommendation\venv\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib

then i ran cmake install command again. it told me requirement is already satisfied.
(venv) PS C:\myFiles\dev\Hair_Style_Recommendation> python -m pip install cmake
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in c:\myfiles\dev\hair_style_recommendation\venv\lib\site-packages (3.29.3)

i checked in venv -> Scripts and cmake.exe does exist there, however pip can't find it.

how do i fix this issue?
does this have to do with the way cmake is being invoked? File "C:\myFiles\dev\Hair_Style_Recommendation\venv\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake' why does this try to access __main__.py on an executable file?


it may need C/C++ program cmake.exe (which can be part of C/C++ compiler). And if it needs Python module cmake then it can't have name cmake.exe but cmake

Download CMake

i installed cmake separately (outside of pip) as well using msys2. cmake is also in windows path and cmake --version through terminal does output the version number. still, dlib won't install

frankly I don't understand why error shows Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py - did you create folder Scripts\cmake.exe with file __main__.py ? Maybe you have to remove it because it can make problem to find real cmake.exe

I try to install dlib on my Linux and I don't need to install pip install cmake but I have command cmake in different place (in folder with other C/C++ programs) . Maybe you should remove cmakeinstalled with pip, and download version from web page.

@furas no i did not create any folder manually. just initialized a venv using pip and tried installing dlib

@furas uninstalled the pip version of cmake, i have cmake installed already from the official cmake website and also present in windows path. still the same error, cannot install dlib (says cmake must be installed)

did you check if you can run it in console in any folder without using full path? I don't use Windows so I can't check this problem on my computer. I may only suggest to download code from GitHub and run cmake manually to compiler it - documentation for compilation
